# strange effects in zsh after changing prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

I've just installed Zsh and written my own custom prompt. I also use emacs formatting in `~/.zshrc` which says `bindkey -e`. Now when I open the shell, for some reason, it acts very weird.

For example if I just type `cd Do` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get this:

[image]

Another example, I am in ~/Downloads/Guns N' Roses - 1988 - G N' R Lies directory and I write `pwd`. After I type letter <kbd>w</kbd> everything disappears and cursor goes to beginning of next line. End result I get working directory, but it looks like this (keep in mind I typed `pwd`):

[image]

This does not happen when I am in a shorter directory like `home`.

What is going on here? Is it because of my PROMPT, or is it just how emacs typing works?

This is my prompt code in `~/zshrc`

```
PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%
{$fg[blue]%}%m$fg[black]|$fg[green]%* %{$fg[yellow]%}%1~ %{$reset_color%}% "
```

Comment: Can you post your `.zshrc` in a pastebin (such as [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com))?

Comment: Sure: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7653783/ I think it may be related to  this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722951/text-disappears-when-typing-long-commands-in-zsh-on-osx But I couldn't find what's exactly wrong with my prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was color tags were not inside `%{...%}`. Correct sequence is now:

```
PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m%{$fg[black]%}|%{$fg[green]%}%* %{$fg[yellow]%}%1~ %{$reset_color%}% "
```